# Multilingual Umbraco Website cannot be scraped?

Tags: dns, umbraco

I have created a multilingual Umbraco website which has 3 domain names pointing to it for each language. The site has gone live and people are starting to share links to it on LinkedIn and other social media. I have metadata in the website which should be picked up when these links are shared. On LinkedIn when the link is shared it has 'coming soon' as the strap-line, which is what was in the holding page months ago suggesting the site isn't being re-scraped.

I used the Facebook link debugging tool and that was returning a run-time error with a 500 response code.

My co-worker insists that there is nothing wrong with the DNS and there aren't any errors in the code of the website so I am wondering if anyone has any ideas why the website cannot be scraped?

It also has another issue where one of the domains sometimes doesn't redirect to it's www. version despite have a redirect on the DNS which may be related.

Is there some specific Umbraco configuration that I may have missed? Or a bug within Umbraco that may cause this?

Aside from this issue the website is working fine, it is just these scrapers seem to be unable to hit the website successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have meta data set for encoding? see https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations probably long shot.

Comment: Thank-you for responding but this wasn't the cause of the issue.

Comment: so what was the issue  ?:)

Comment: It has been a while since I looked at this but I believe it was a broken custom method in umbraco causing this issue.